# Go channels in recursive algorithm results in duplicate values

Tags: algorithm, go, recursion, concurrency

### Starting point

I have an implementation of [Heap's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm) to create all permutations of a set in Go:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
  set := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
  Permutation(set, len(set))
}

func Permutation(a []string, k int) {
  if k == 1 {
    fmt.Println(a)
  }
  for i := 0; i < k; i++ {
    Permutation(a, k-1)
    if k%2 == 0 {
      a[i], a[k-1] = a[k-1], a[i]
    } else {
      a[0], a[k-1] = a[k-1], a[0]
    }
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
[a b c]
[b a c]
[c a b]
[a c b]
[b c a]
[c b a]
```

It prints out the correct six permutations of the input set, so everything works.

### Problem

But now I would like to return the permutations to the caller rather than printing them out in the function.

I tried to do this by passing a channel into the function and then sending each permutation to the channel instead of printing it:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
  set := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
  c := make(chan []string)

  go Permutation(set, len(set), c)

  for s := range c {
    fmt.Println(s)
  }
}

func Permutation(a []string, k int, c chan []string) {
  if k == 1 {
    c <- a          // <<<========= Main change
  }
  for i := 0; i < k; i++ {
    Permutation(a, k-1, c)
    if k%2 == 0 {
      a[i], a[k-1] = a[k-1], a[i]
    } else {
      a[0], a[k-1] = a[k-1], a[0]
    }
  }
  if k == len(a) {
    close(c)
  }
}
```

But now the output is like this:

```
[b a c]
[b a c]
[a c b]
[a c b]
[c b a]
[c b a]
```

There are still six permutations, but there are duplicates of the same permutations.

**Why is that happening?**

**As seen in the starting point, the algorithm seems to be correct and the main change is that the values of `a` are sent to the channel rather than printed out in the indicated line in the `Permutation` function body.**

Comment: That's not an accurate transcription of the algorithm on the Wikipedia page you link to. Rather, it is an implementation of the "Frequent Misimplementation" shown [futher down in the page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm#Frequent_Mis-implementations). Heap's algorithm should always be verified with k=4 (at least) because the common error doesn't affect the k=3 case in any obvious way.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I took the implementation from somewhere. It produced the correct results too, but less efficiently.

Comment: but the results are not correct. Heap's algorithm produces successive permutations which differ in just a single swap of two elements. The incorrect implementation does not satisfy this requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this, you sent the slice `a` to the main goroutine:

```
  if k == 1 {
    c <- a
  }
```

And while main goroutine is working to print it, you start modifying `a`. So the slice is being modified as you print.

You can send a copy instead:

```
if k == 1 {
   x := make([]string, len(a))
   copy(x,a)
   c <- x
}
```

Comment: This is correct but misleading. You call `a` a pointer, but it is not. `a` is a slice, whose underlying implementation happens to contain a pointer to an array.

Comment: I fixed the post. `a` is a slice.